# Creation date from assets file

Tags: android

is any way to check creation date by assets file?

I try use "File", but is wrong way.

```
File f = new File("file:///android_asset/" + "file.zip");
        Log.i("FILE CREATION DATE (IN DEVICE)", new Date(f.lastModified()).toString());
```

Comment: What would you like to do with the information? There's likely a better solution for the problem. Anyway, `file:///android_asset` only works with a webview.

Comment: I need this for my simple method